# Name for generalization of trees to digraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology, trees, directed-graphs

One definition of [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) in graph theory could be as follows:

> A tree is a(n undirected) graph for which there is a unique (undirected) [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) between any pair of vertices.

This suggest a possible definition of "directed tree":

> A "directed tree" is a directed graph for which there is a unique [directed path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) between any pair of vertices.

**Question:** Is there an established name for the "directed trees" defined above?

Note that these "directed trees" are *not* [arborescences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory)) (rooted directed trees). For example, a directed cycle is a "directed tree" in the above sense; and indeed all "directed trees" in the above sense are basically trees of directed cycles.

Comment: Closely related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitree

Comment: @RobPratt the examples have no strongly connected, i.e. are special kinds of DAGs whereas the suggested generalizations of trees are strongly connected.

Comment: In contrast to undirected trees, where the cardinality of edges is fixed to $n-1$, it can be anything from $n$ to $2(n-1)$ in the directed case; the extremes being a directed Hamilton cycle, resp. an undirected tree after having replaced each of its undirected edges with a pair of antiparallel arcs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I remember that I *do* know what these digraphs are called. A "directed tree" in the sense defined above is usually called a **directed cactus**. See for example Section 3 of "Remarks on Hamiltonian properties of powers of digraphs" by Günter Schaar (https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(94)90107-4):

> A strongly connected (finite) digraph G, each edge of which is contained in at most (and thus, in exactly) one directed cycle in G, is called a *directed cactus*.

I learned this terminology from Section 2.5 of "CoEulerian graphs" by Matthew Farrell and Lionel Levine (https://doi.org/10.1090/proc/12952). They show these directed cactuses are exactly the digraphs that are both Eulerian and coEulerian, where "coEulerian" is a new concept they introduce in that paper.

I guess technically it is a little unclear whether loops are allowed (for your "directed trees" or for directed cactuses). That should just be specified.

Comment: Loops in the sense of directed Hamilton cycles are allowed; ruling them out would be unnatural and allowing them makes it possible to develop heuristics for ATSPs that start from a greedily constructed directed tree.

Comment: I mean loops in the usual sense, an edge from a vertex to itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory).